# Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor

I'm trying to add additional attribute **data-icon** to my Action Link, but I'm getting the error below:

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must
>   be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

**Works:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Details", "Profile", new { id = 11 }, 
            new { @rel = "external", @id = "btnProfile" })
```

**Exception:**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Details", "Profile", new { id = 11 }, 
            new { @rel = "external", @id = "btnProfile", @data-icon = "gear" })
```

Comment: instead of `@data-icon` use `@data_icon`

Comment: gives the same exception

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify data attributes in razor, e.g., data-externalid="23151" on @this.Html.CheckBoxFor(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9444805/how-to-specify-data-attributes-in-razor-e-g-data-externalid-23151-on-this)

Answer (score 30):

**UPDATE:** From Xander's comment above, use `data_icon = "gear"`

You can use an `IDictionary<string, object>` in place of the anonymous object for HTML attributes:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Details", "Profile", new { id = 11 }
    , new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "rel", "external" }, 
        { "id", "btnProfile" },
        { "data-icon", "gear" },
    })
```

See this overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504988.aspx

The helper you are using is just a convenient method of creating the dictionary, but behind the scenes the dictionary is created anyway.

Comment: When I do this, it renders the link like: `<a comparer="System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer1[System.String]" count="1" keys="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2+KeyCollection[System.String,System.Object]" values="System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2+ValueCollection[System.String,System.Object]" href="/Account/LogOff/1" class="ui-link">Log Off</a>`

Comment: I had this problem with a period/dot in my parameter (a class Filter with a member that I wanted to pass), I found the following worked...
`@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Details", new RouteValueDictionary{ {"filter.member", myvalue.ToString() } } )`

Hope the formatting works - basically use RouteValueDictionary instead of the anonymous type?

Answer (score 19):

I think you use underscore like **data_icon** and it translates it

Comment: perfect answer.

Answer (score 3):

I just use the following

```
@using System.Web.Routing

@{
    RouteValueDictionary RouteValues = new RouteValueDictionary();

    RouteValues["id"] = 11;
    RouteValues[Some_Name] = Some_Value; //do this with as many name/value pairs 
                                         //as you like
}

@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Action", "Controller", RouteValues)
```

which I learnt from Jon's answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258847/create-routevalues-anonymous-type-programmatically-in-asp-net-mvc-3).

I have mainly used this in my controllers to provide the route values for `RedirectToAction()` methods, but i don't see why it shouldn't work in your view, you will need to add a `@using System.Web.Routing;` though.

Answer (score 0):

Use "data_icon" instead of "data-icon".

```
        @Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Details", "Profile", new { id = 11 }, 
        new { @rel = "external", @id = "btnProfile", @data_icon = "gear" })
```

The _ will automatically be converted to - in the resulting markup.