# Build Dynamic parameter objects in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, parameters

Hi I am trying to create one common ActionResult that can return redirectToAction with dynamic ActionName, ControllerName and object Parameter if any

```
public ActionResult partner()
        {
//Building my params
obj.parameters = string.Format("cId = {0}, aId= {1}", CustomerID, Session["LocationId"]);
 return RedirectToAction(obj.actionName, obj.controllerName, string.IsNullOrEmpty(obj.parameters) ? null : new { obj.parameters });
}
```

I am not sure if this is possible in MVC.
Did any one had such requirement? is there any work around to achieve something like this.

Comment: cant you get these values from RouteData

Comment: no. these params are build based on business logic. in some instance there may be few parameters and some time none. With the above code it is rendering the url as /Controller/Action?parameters="cid=2,aid=3"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple ideas that may help you out:

**Option 1**: Use an anonymously typed object containing the route values.

> ```
> obj.parameters = new { cId = CustomerID, aId = Session["LocationId"] };
> return RedirectToAction(obj.actionName, obj.controllerName, obj.parameters);
> ```

**Option 2**: Use a `RouteValueDictionary` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10258879/316621) to a similar question.

> ```
> obj.parameters = new RouteValueDictionary();
> obj.parameters['cId'] = CustomerID;
> obj.parameters['aId'] = Session["LocationId"];
> return RedirectToAction(obj.actionName, obj.controllerName, obj.parameters);
> ```