# Parameter return in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to pass parameter grid-page, but i get error while compiling

> Error 2   Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type
>   members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or
>   member access.
>
> return RedirectToAction("Grid", new { sukurta = item.lic_plate,
>   grid-page = 2 });

Comment: Use `grid_page`. Identifiers can't contain a hyphen.

Comment: A `-` is not a valid character for a variable name.

Comment: @Stijn Might as well post that as an answer since it's... the answer.

Comment: @AntP I think the question should be closed as a typo instead. Feel free to post an answer though if think it should stay open, I don't mind :)

Comment: @Stijn I'm not so sure - in this instance it's a typo, but the same situation could easily arise as a genuine "what does this error mean," scenario, so it's probably worth keeping (with a better title).

Comment: @AntP I just found a [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196776/invalid-anonymous-type-member-declarator-anonymous-type-members-must-be-declare), it's for `ActionLink` but it's the same principle. I can't vote again to close, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this code
---------------
My simple suggestion is just remove '-' symbol
public ActionResult Index()
            {

                  return RedirectToAction("About" , new
                  {
                        sukurta = "a" ,
                        grid_page = "3"
                  });
            }

            public ActionResult About( string sukurta , string grid_page )
            {


                  return View();
            }
```